# "bad src image pointer" after read frame of video in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gimp

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("Path_to_directory\\%03d.jpg"); 
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_frames; ++i)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        //...
    }
```

In the line "cap >> frame;" "bad src image pointer" is printed to console. None of the following frames of video could not be retrieved.

Is there a specific property of image should have to captured with VideoCapture then retrieving to a Mat?

Probably there is, because frames could be retrieved with code above. However after I manipulated them with Gimp, then I saved with overwriting them. Their some property should be changed while overwriting, but I don't know what are those.

Thanks.

Note: OpenCV version 2.4.9

Comment: most probably your images went bad, when you manipulated them. (not so much a coding problem). also, do *not* save them as jpg, those are quite problematic with image-processing due to lossy compression.

Comment: Thank you @berak. Also after doing manipulation with Paint there wasn't such problem.

Comment: As far as I remember .bmp is lossless compression. Is it? Which extension should I use?

Comment: yes. use bmp, or png.